# How to disable Combobox slide animation effect in MFC?

Tags: mfc, combobox

Is there any way I can disable slide animation effect of a particular combo-box in MFC?

Generally combo-box slides downwards while opening, but if it doesn't fit into screen then it slides upwards. Can we override this default behavior and make combo-box slide upwards everytime?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? What is it you are trying to accomplish with that?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a combobox control is considered to have a drop-down style. You appear to want consistent "drop-up" behavior instead. My initial thought was to change the DrawMode to Owner-Draw but this only gives you control over the visual aspect of each item; you actually want the selection rectangle to always appear above the drop-down arrow. However, changing the Dock property may do the trick. I suggest calling set_Dock() with a DockStyle of "Bottom": myDropUpComboBox.set_Dock(DockStyle.Bottom);

Another option is to create your own combobox-like class based upon the base control class. This would involve considerable code to mimic most of the standard behavior provided by a basic combobox.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But set_Dock() method is of .NET framework. I require a solution in MFC (version is Visual C++ 2003).